# how to use mod in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, modulo, irvine32

I have a question on assembly x86 architecture.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
day BYTE 0
month BYTE 0
year BYTE 0

a BYTE 0
y BYTE 0
m BYTE 0
count BYTE 0

prompt1 BYTE "enter month: ",0
prompt2 BYTE "enter day: ",0
prompt3 BYTE "enter an year: ",0
prompt4 BYTE " the day of the week is ",0
.code
main PROC

mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
call writeString
mov eax, OFFSET month
mov ecx, 19
call readInt
call crlf

mov edx, OFFSET prompt2
call writeString
mov eax, OFFSET day
mov ecx, 19
call readInt
call crlf

mov edx, OFFSET prompt3
call writeString
mov eax, OFFSET year
mov ecx, 19
call readInt
call crlf

mov al, 14
sub al, month
mov bl, 12
div bl
mov a, al
mov al, 0

mov ah, year
sub ah, a
mov y, ah
mov ah, 0

mov bh, 12
mul a
add bh, a
mov ch, 2
sub bh, ch
mov m, bh
mov bh, 0
mov ch, 0

mov al, 31
mul m
mov ah, 12
div ah

mov bl, y
mov bh, day
add bh, y

mov cl, y
mov ch, 4
div ch
add bh, cl

mov dl, y
mov dh, 4
div dh
add bh, cl
add bh, al
mov al, 0

mov al, 7 // mod 7
div al



    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

So I am supposed to do these arithmetic equations:

```
a = (14 - month) / 12
y = year - a
m = month + (12 * a) - 2
d = (day + y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + (31 * m / 12)) % 7
```

For the last equation of `mod 7`, I got an error, "integer overflow", this is due to using `bl` I think.

If I do something like this

```
mov ax, "thing in parenthesis" 
mov cl, 7
div cl
```

then I would get `al` is quotient, `ah` is remainder.

But how would I do `mod` without having to use `ax` register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dividing by a byte value you're dividing `AX` and storing the quotient in `AL`. Therefore you need to make sure that the quotient will fit in 8 bits, or you get the error that you describe in your question.

One way of accomplishing this is to clear `AH` before the division. I.e.

```
MOV AH,0
```

or

```
XOR AH,AH
```

For a signed division (`IDIV`) you'd use `CBW` to sign-extend `AL` into `AX`.

If your question was how to fix your issue without having to touch `AH`, then the answer is "you can't". There's no point to it anyway since `AH` still will be modified by the `DIV` instruction (to hold the remainder).

Comment: You've got more than one `div` in your code, so you need to fix all of them. The `div ah` will obviously have to be changed to use another divisor than `ah`.